# How we create standard class in VB 2008

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I just wonder if I can create an standard class in VB 2008

I am trying to create a function GetRow(txtSQL) which accepts sql as parameter. I wanted this function to return an object which contains columns of database tables as properties so i could use as

```
 myObj=GetRow("select name, address from tbl_contacts where id=1")
 txtname.text=myObj.name
```

Comment: What have you tried, I presume what you have showed is the signature of the function that you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you cannot have properties that are generated at run time available at design time. Since the SQL is simply a string, the compiler doesn't know that .Name needs to be a property.

The best I can offer you is as follows:

```
 Function GetRow(cnn As SqlConnection, sql As String) As DataRow
    Using dtb As New DataTable
      Using dad As New SqlDataAdapter(sql, cnn)
        dad.Fill(dtb)
      End Using
      If dtb.Rows.Count >= 1 Then
        Return dtb.Rows(0)
      Else
        Return Nothing
      End If
    End Using
  End Function

  Sub test()
    Using cnn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=mycomputername;Timeout=10;User ID=myusername;Password=mypassword;")
      cnn.Open()
      Dim strSql As String = "select name, address from tbl_contacts where id=1"
      Dim drw As DataRow = GetRow(cnn, strSql)
      txtName.text = CStr(drw("name"))
      cnn.Close
    End Using
  End Sub
```

Comment: I am very happy and sad as well because I have been using this method for a log time to fill the datagridview.